# Stacked math with lefthand braces around selected lines

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols, stackengine, substack

Following

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\stackMath
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{G} = \stackunder{p6mm}{\vec{a},\vec{b}} \overset{t[\mathit{3}]}{>}
    \mathcal{Z} = \stackunder{c2mm}{\braceVectorstack{{\vec{a}-\vec{b},\vec{a}+\vec{b}} {\vec{a}+2\vec{b},-\vec{a}} {\textcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}}}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

I want to add another block in separate curly braces into the understack and have only a brace on the left side. See the image modified with an image editor:

[image]

Nesting of `\Shortunderstack{ \braceVectorstack{} ...}` looks like is not possible. The naive attempt

```
    \mathcal{Z} = \Shortunderstack{{c2mm} {\braceVectorstack{{\vec{a}-\vec{b},\vec{a}+\vec{b}} {\vec{a}+2\vec{b},-\vec{a}} {\textcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}}}}}
```

gives me

```
l.12 ...xtcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}}}}}


./demo.tex:12: Package listofitems Error: 3 is an invalid index, index [] retained.
```

How can I achieve this with the package *stackengine* or a different way/package?

The documentation of *stackengine* states

> Except in circumstances that require the particular features of this
>   package, stackengine may not be the best package for math mode since
>   there are many packages that already cater directly to the need to
>   stack and align mathematical objects.

Actually, I only know the package *amsmath* with `\substack`, `\overset`, `\underset`. I would appreciate if someone could mention a few of the many packages the author is referring to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of what the intended output should be, but in this case I'd just go with an `array`, and maybe also the `cases` environment from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathcal{Z} =
\begin{array}[t]{l}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{foo}\\
\begin{cases}
\vec{a}-\vec{b},\vec{a}+\vec{b}\\
\vec{a}+2\vec{b},-\vec{a}\\
\textcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}
\end{cases}
\\
\begin{cases}
\vec{a}-\vec{b},\vec{a}+\vec{b}\\
\vec{a}+2\vec{b},-\vec{a}\\
\textcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}
\end{cases}
\end{array}
%
= % second version
%
\begin{array}[t]{l}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{foo}\\
\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\vec{a}-\vec{b},\vec{a}+\vec{b}\\
\vec{a}+2\vec{b},-\vec{a}\\
\textcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}
\end{array}\right.
\\[4ex]
\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\vec{a}-\vec{b},\vec{a}+\vec{b}\\
\vec{a}+2\vec{b},-\vec{a}\\
\textcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've written "*foo*" in the first line because I didn't understand whether *c2mm* was a typo or not.

Comment: I was not aware that the baseline is matched with the first row in a top-aligned array. I am happy to have learned this. So thanks for your answer. BTW [c2mm](http://www.cryst.ehu.es/cgi-bin/plane/programs/nph-plane_maxsub?gnum=17&type=plane&from=table) is a 2D crystallographic group; it is not a typo.

Comment: @Hotschke Learned something new,,, I wasn't  sure because c2mm looked through my TeX glasses like a `c` column and `2mm`... `:-)`

Comment: The optional argument `[pos]` of  the environments `array` and `tabular` is described in the section **8.23 Tabular** of the *unofficial reference manual for LaTeX2e*. The section for array refers to 8.23 for the argument `[pos]`. This manual is available on [ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/latex2e-help-texinfo), typically on the command line via [$ texdoc latex2e](http://texdoc.net/), and on [latexref.xyz](https://latexref.xyz/tabular.html#tabular) as pdf or html. Also someone converted into a docset for [zeal/dash](https://zealdocs.org/).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\Shortunderstack` with two `cases` environments or `\stackunder` with two blocks in a `blockarray` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\stackMath
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{G} = \stackunder{p6mm}{\vec{a},\vec{b}} \overset{t[\mathit{3}]}{>}
    \mathcal{Z} = \Shortunderstack{{c2mm} {\begin{dcases}\begin{matrix}\vec{a}-\vec{b},\vec{a}+\vec{b}\\ \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-\vec{a}\\ \textcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}\end{matrix}\end{dcases}} { \begin{dcases}\vec{a}-\vec{b},\vec{a}+\vec{b}\\ \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-\vec{a}\\ \textcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}\end{dcases}}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     \mathcal{G} = \stackunder{p6mm}{\vec{a},\vec{b}} \overset{t[\mathit{3}]}{>}
     \mathcal{Z} = \stackunder{c2mm}{\begin{blockarray}{c}\begin{block}{\{c}\vec{a}-\vec{b},\vec{a}+\vec{b}\\ \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-\vec{a}\\ \textcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}\\ \end{block}\begin{block}{\{r}\vec{a}-\vec{b},\vec{a}+\vec{b}\\ \vec{a}+2\vec{b},-\vec{a}\\ \textcolor{red}{2\vec{a}+\vec{b},\vec{b}}\\ \end{block}\end{blockarray}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### Nesting of `\stackunder{anchor}{\stackunder{b1}{\stackunder{b2}{...}}}`

I have figured out another solution using *stackengine* by nesting `\stackunder{}` and using `\left\{\Vectorstack{item1 item2 item3}\right.` for the blocks.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\stackMath
\begin{equation*}
      \mathcal{Z} = \stackunder
      {c2mm}
      {\stackunder
         {\left\{\Vectorstack{block1 block1 block1}\right.}
         {\stackunder
           {\left\{\Vectorstack{block2 block2 block2}\right.}
           {\left\{\Vectorstack{block3 block3 block3}\right.}
         }
      }
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]